# "A Java Runtime Error Environment...No Java virtual machine was found after searching..."

Tags: eclipse

I just installed eclipse on my windows 8 computer and I get this error when trying to run eclipse. I'm not really sure whats going on I already have the Java SDK on my computer.

Error message:

[image]

My Eclipse.ini text file (its just one long line in textpad):

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: Do you have JAVA located in your PATH variable?

Comment: Which is the PATH variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the eclipse icon and "run as administrator", worth a shot!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding:
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\bin\javaw.exe

before -vmargs
Make sure there is a new line after -vm